# Making LET spill

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spill-range

I have the current formula

```
=LET(
    rad, ROW(C2),
    sumArea, SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(rad,3)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(rad+5,3))),
    result, sumArea/INDIRECT(ADDRESS(rad+6,2)),
    result
)
```

which calculates a five day change from the value in cell B7 with the change column C. It works perfectly when just giving the `ROW(C2)` argument, but I ideally want it to work with spill, since the C column is itself spilled. When I give the argument `ROW(C2#)`, it does spill, but returns a value error in each of the spilled results.

Is it not possible to use the LET function this way, or can I change something to make it work? I'm thankful for any guidance I can get! :D

---

Sample data:

[image]

The value -28.6% is calculated by taking `SUM(-2,2,2,-5,-1)/14`.

Comment: Use `BYROW()` or `MAP()` function.

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected result - that makes it easier to help you.

Comment: @Ike Thanks for the suggestion but it is quite clearly explained in the question. However, that is besides the point; my question is about letting the LET function spill its result to several cells.

Comment: e.g. you don't need volatile `INDIRECT` - I would have shown that - but only with sample data.

Comment: @Ike Fine, you sparked my interest and now I have added sample data. How can I avoid using ```INDIRECT```?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have suggested, using `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS` is not generally a good idea (not least as the functions are volatile so will recalculate every time the sheet changes).

[image]

With the formula in cell B3

```
=LET(a,A3:A9,o,B1,n,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)-o),e,INDEX(a,n),s,INDEX(a,n+o),(e-s)/s)
```

Where B1 is the variable lookback (eg 5 days)

*If you have too much time on your hands*, or think you might want to re-use this formula, create a `Name` via the Formulas / Define Name menu:

[image]

And then the formula in B3 is now:

```
=PeriodChange(A3:A9,B1)
```

eg: if you still wanted the helper column of 1-period changes:

```
=PeriodChange(A3:A9,1)
```

EDIT:

This alternative formula is a little more flexible, as it allows you to pass in an array with more than one column, using `CHOOSEROWS` rather than `INDEX`:

```
=LET(a,A3:B9,o,B1,n,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)-o),i,LAMBDA(m,CHOOSEROWS(a,m)),e,i(n),s,i(n+o),(e-s)/s)
```

Using a `LAMBDA` alias for the `CHOOSEROWS` function cuts down the typing.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the data it seems you can just use:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(r,A1:A7,d,DROP(r,5),(DROP(r,-5)-d)/d)
```

Obviously `A1:A7` is a placeholder for your initial data, not the helper column.

Comment: Out of interest, why the `-` and not `TAKE(r,ROWS(r)-5)-d`?

Comment: @DS_London, because that is too obvious =). Thanks for the sharp pair of eyes I was lacking here for a second. I also removed `TAKE()` and `ROWS()`. Not needed.

Comment: I must make DROP and TAKE a more regular part of my repertoire!

Comment: Thanks, but my version of Excel does not seem to contain the DROP function. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the very helpful comment I got from @Harun24hr, I managed to solve this. My revised method is to create a lambda function that contains the LET function that works when having a single cell input, and then using BYROW to perform the calculation over C2#.

The final formula looks like this:

```
=BYROW(C2#,
     LAMBDA(array,
             LET(
             rad, ROW(array),
             sumArea, SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(rad,3)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(rad+5,3))),
             result, sumArea/INDIRECT(ADDRESS(rad+6,2)),
             result
             )
     )
)
```

I still don't know whether the `LET` function can be reliably spilled but this workaroud solves the problem of it not spilling correctly in my case.

Comment: Your sample doesn't show column letters so it is unclear which data your formula is using. I am positive the INDIRECT is unneeded but without a complete example that is impossible to try. You must help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution w/o helper column for delta and w/o indirect:

```
=LET(dataBase,B2:B8,
dataDelta,dataBase - DROP(dataBase,1),
BYROW(dataBase,LAMBDA(r,
           LET(rowR,ROW(r),
                  sumArea,SUM(FILTER(dataDelta,(ROW(dataBase)>=rowR)*(ROW(dataBase)<=rowR+4),0)),
                  IFNA(sumArea/INDEX(dataBase,rowR+4),"")))))
```

[image]